Counting the Number of Occurrences of Multiple Single Characters in a Range
I have made an attendance tracker in which adding a letter to a cell denotes the type of "attendance" that is being tracked within a range (monthly range, each day is a cell).
A for absent, T for late time change request, S for late conversion, L for late call out. I have a COUNTIF formula tabulating the letters placed in the cell that is counted in individual cells, but I realize now I may need to enter multiple letters on a single day/single cell.
I am unsure how to write a formula for counting the number of occurrences of a single letter, but potentially multiple letters within the single cell of a range.

I have tried looking at LEN formulas but am stuck!

That screenshot really shows us nearly nothing. Please share some markdown data with data to reproduce your problem along with the expected result. https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables

You may need MID() function with SEQUENCE() to separate each character from a single cell.

Is there potentially multiple of the same characters in a single cell, e.g. "AALTSSSA"?

One approach with FIND function
=SUM(IF(IFERROR(FIND(C$4,$A$2:$A$9),0)>0,1,0))
in cell D4. Copy D4 to the other result cells.

